# Datatable - How to search and export data only when the search is not null

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

This is the approach I have tried so far:

```
$("#ExportPDF").on("click", function() {
    var datatable = $('#myTable').DataTable();                    
    if (! datatable.data().any()) {
        console.log( 'the table is actually empty' );                       
    }
    else{
        var table = $('#myTable').DataTable().search('something');
        table.button( '.buttons-pdf' ).trigger();
    }
});
```

When my table is empty, it does not export anything, which is perfect for me.

Now when the table contains elements, I do a search on a keyword `something`; if items are found they export them. But when no information is found it still exports an empty PDF.

How to avoid exporting an empty PDF?

Comment: If you add `console.log( table );` to the else clause what is the output ?

Comment: This: `s {context: Array(1), selector: {…}, tables: ƒ, table: ƒ, draw: ƒ, …}`. I admit that I do not quite understand what it means... @Zakaria Acharki Moreover, when I add the condition you suggest (`if (table != " ")`), it still exports an empty PDF. She seems to have no impact.

Answer (score 0):

Check the returned array before triggering the button :

```
else {
  var table = $('#myTable').DataTable().search('something');
  if( table != "" ){
    table.button('.buttons-pdf').trigger();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tableid').dataTable({
    "fnDrawCallback": function () {
        var table = $('#tableid').DataTable();
        if (table.data().length === 0)
            table.buttons('.buttons-html5').attr('disabled', true);
        else
            table.buttons('.buttons-html5').attr('disabled', false);

    }
});
```